# Proper way (move semantics) to return a std::vector from function calling in C++11

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, move-semantics, return-value-optimization

I want to fill std::vector (or some other STL container):

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(int _n, const Bar &_m);
private:
  std::vector<Foo> fooes_;
}
```

*1.Good looking ctor, expensive performance*

```
std::vector<Foo> get_vector(int _n, const Bar &_m) {
  std::vector<Foo> ret;
  ... // filling ret depending from arguments
  return ret;
}

Foo::Foo(int _n, const Bar &_m) : fooes_(get_vector(_n, _m) {}
```

*2. Better performance, worse looking ctor*

```
void fill_vector(int _n, const Bar &_m, std::vector<Foo> &_ret) {
  ... // filling ret depending from arguments
}

Foo::Foo(int _n, const Bar &_m) { fill_vector(_n, _m, fooes_); }
```

Is it possible to rewrite `get_vector` function from 1st example with C++0x (move semantics features and so on) to avoid redundant copying and constructor calls?

Comment: Can you clarify whether your `_m` parameter is going to be modified by those functions? And what is being done with `_m` inside those functions? Is it copied in `get_vector`?

Comment: @Johannes - Thank you for your deleted answer (+1). I added 2 different argument just for illustration. I'm not too interested in their nature. You're right, it is better to add a const, so as not to cause confusion. I do not quite understand rvalue references. Is it `Bar` has to have move ctor in `Foo::Foo(int _n, Bar _m) fooes_(get_vector(_n, move(_m)) {}`?

Comment: Instead of describing here all the details of RVO, moving, etc. here is link to the article that looks in the details of this: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you're using a C++0x-compatible compiler and standard library, you get better performance from the first example **without doing anything**. The return value of `get_vector(_n, _m)` is a temporary, and the move constructor for `std::vector` (a constructor taking an rvalue reference) will automatically be called with no further work on your part.

In general, non-library writers won't need to use rvalue references directly; you'll just reap a decent chunk of the benefits automatically.

Answer (score 16):

I believe (1) and (2) have identical performance even without C++0x, as long as your compiler does the Named Return Value Optimization, which I believe most do. Neither should do any copies, **nor any moves**.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, because if so I misunderstand NRVO.

Comment: That is correct. And even in C++0x, compiler first considers RVO, and if it can't it considers moving object, if that is not allowed it does the copying as the last resort.

Answer (score 7):

In the particular case that you are considering, the first implementation is just as efficient as the second. The compiler will optimize the copy of `ret` in the `get_vector` function to the return value, and it will use *move semantics* to transfer ownership of the vector to the container class. Move construction in a vector requires (implementation dependent, but a good approximation is) 3 pointer copies, independently of the number and sizes of the elements in the container. Passing the vector as a reference to be modified requires a single pointer copy (approximate cost again), but any operation you perform on the vector will dominate the cost of either option.

There are some very specific circumstances when passing a vector into a function for modification might be faster, but those are rare and more related to the domain than to the vector itself. Just ignore that, code first for maintainability, and if the program is slow, profile, determine where the cost of the program is, and only then think on optimizing. The interesting part is that once you have profiled, you probably know what the bottleneck is and that means you will have hints into what to change.

Comment: With regards to performance, it depends: if you write something like `std::vector<Foo> v(get_vector(...))`, the compiler should be able to optimize the copy out.  If you do `v = get_vector(...)` on an existing `std::vector<Foo>`, probably not.

Comment: @James Kanze: that is the underlying reason for the comment *some specific circumstances when passing a vector might be faster*. Performing a `clear()` in the container will not release the memory, and if the new elements fit in the same container, then no memory acquisition will be required either, so it will be more efficient. But talking about object creation (as in the case of initialization of a member in the question), they will be equivalent.

Comment: @David Rodriguez Or not.  The only way to be sure is to try both, and measure (and it's not worth the bother until there really is a performance problem).  In one or two special cases, I've found it faster to move a variable outside of a loop, for the reason you mention: once the memory is allocated, it won't be freed, so you end up with less reallocations.  (But it's not general.)  My advice is to just return the container, until it becomes a performance problem, then experiment with different solutions, to find one which solves the problem.

Comment: @James : If you do `v = get_vector(...)` on an existing `std::vector<Foo>`, there is no copy; this invoke's `vector<>`'s move-assignment operator since `get_vector` returns an rvalue. I don't see what you're getting at...

Comment: @ildjarn Not with my compilers, it doesn't.  Move semantics aren't available with most compilers, and the ones I use don't use them in the standard library even if they are available.

Comment: @James : It does with my compiler (VC++ 2010), and the FDIS  mandates that it should; that's good enough for me.

Comment: @idljarn: I have to agree with James here: the FDIS is not even an approved standard, and not everyone can use the latest compiler available for their platform (heck, I don't even use windows at all!)

Comment: @David : The question is about _move semantics in C++0x_ -- you're saying that for a question tagged `c++0x`, we shouldn't regard the C++0x FDIS as authoritative? That makes no sense whatsoever, especially considering that in this case there are multiple shipping compilers that do adhere to the FDIS in this respect. On the other hand, applying C++03 rules to a question labeled and tagged C++0x is rather useless, and seems to be what you're advocating. Help me out here, is this a joke?

Comment: @ildjarn: :) I missed the tag. My bad