# Can a vector allocated on the "stack" be passed from function to function?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I know that variables allocated on that stack of a function become inaccessible when the function finishes execution. However, vector types allocate their elements on the heap no matter how they are allocated. So for instance,

```
vector<int> A;
```

will allocate space for its elements on the heap instead of the stack.

My question is, assume I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // initialize a vector
    vector<int> A = initVector(100000);

    // do something with the vector...

    return 0;
}


// initialize the vector
vector<int> initVector(int size) {
    vector<int> A (size);  // initialize the vector "on the stack"

    // fill the vector with a sequence of numbers...
    int counter = 0;
    for (vector<int>::iterator i = A.begin(); i != A.end(); i++) {
        (*i) = counter++;
    }

    return A;
}
```

Will I have memory access problems when using the vector A in the main function? I tried this several times and they all worked normally, but I'm scared that this might just be luck.

The way I see it is, the vector A allocates its elements on the heap, but it has some "overhead" parameters (maybe the size of the vector) allocated on the stack itself. Therefore, using the vector in the main function might result in a memory access problem if these parameters are overwritten by another allocation. Any ideas?

Comment: By your logic, `int add(int a, int b) {int r = a + b; return r}` should have the same problem you suspect for your `initVector`...

Comment: `vector<int> A (size);` => `A` resides on stack but the memory locations it is pointing to resides on heap. The `size` number contiguous memory locations are on heap, while the vector class holds the pointer to the beginning element on the heap. Lets see if someone corrects me.

Comment: TBH, I've been somewhat confused by this kind of thing as well.  Whenever I've had any doubt, I've allocated the vector as well, eg: 'vector<int> *a; a=new vector<int>;' and then returned the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work normally because the memory for the elements are allocated and that is what will be used to build the `vector<int> A =` variable. However, performance wise, it is not the best idea.

I would suggest changing your function to be the following though

```
void initVector(vector<int>& a, int size)
```

For additional references on usage, please see [Returning a STL vector from a function…](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/7d28351a-488f-4e97-b69e-6e73b43ce8af/) and [[C++] Returning Vector from Function](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=3971175&postcount=3).

For an additional reference on performance (using C++11), please see [Proper way (move semantics) to return a std::vector from function calling in C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211575/proper-way-move-semantics-to-return-a-stdvector-from-function-calling-in-c)

Comment: RVO would probably make that suggested change unnecessary.  But it is a good practice anyway.

Comment: Thanks for links. I agree that this is a better method. I've just always had doubts about how the vector class actually works.

Comment: @josephthomas If I use your method (i.e. passing the vector by reference), will I then be forced to allocated the vector using 'a = new vector<int>'? Or can is there a way around that?

Comment: You do not need to allocator vector<int> at all when passing by reference.

Comment: @Amardeep "good practice anyway" - I disagree. Passing a reference for something that should have been a return value is unclear, and potentially slows down your program. http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: @Rob: I disagree that *in this particular case* it should even be a return value.  A reference parameter vector to a function named "initVector" is quite clear.  In the more general case the article you linked has some excellent points.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 6):

When you do "return A;" you return by value, so you get a copy of the vector -- C++ creates a new instance and calls copy constructor or operator= on it. So in this case it doesn't matter where the memory was allocated as you have to copy it anyway and destroy the old copy (some possible optimizations notwithstanding).

The data in the vector (and all other STL containers) is moved around by value as well, so you store the copy of your integers, not pointers to them. That means your objects can be copied around several times in any container operation and they must implement a copy constructor and/or assignment operator correctly. C++ generates those for you by default (just calling copy ctor on all your member variables), but they don't always do the right thing.

If you want to store pointers in an STL container consider using shared pointer wrappers (std::shared_ptr or boost::shared_ptr). They will ensure the memory is handled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

C++ vector actually has two pieces of memory that are linked with a single pointer. The first one is in stack, and the 2nd one in heap. So you have features of both stack and heap in a single object.

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(10);
vec.push_back(20);
vec.push_back(30);
std::cout << sizeof(vec) << std::endl;
```

Once you run that code, you'll notice that the stack area does not contain the elements, but it still exists. So when you pass the vector from function to another, you'll need to manipulate the stack areas, and the vector will get copied like any other stack-based object.