# Returning matrix(as vector) from function

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am using c++.

I've created in function multidimensional vector to create a new array. Values "size1" and "size2" are coming from another function.
The question is:
How to rename that "void" to let me return array from my function?

```
 void makearray(int size1, int size2) // Yup, it shouldn't be 'void' but... what?
{
    vector<int> x(size1);
    vector<vector<int> > array(size2, x);
//working on array
            return array;

}
```

Comment: More info at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211575/proper-way-move-semantics-to-return-a-stdvector-from-function-calling-in-c

Comment: Make sure it is `vector<vector<int> >`  Don't forget the space at the end.

Comment: @JoshEngelsma: You don't want to return a reference to a __local variable__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just name the type you want to return:

```
vector<vector<int> > makearray(int size1, int size2)
```

or perhaps use a typedef to make it more readable:

```
typedef vector<vector<int> > matrix_type;

matrix_type makearray(int size1, int size2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a function for this. In C++11, the [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) type exists, as per the [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).
Using this type will get you a multidimensional array of Size1 and Size2 dimensions:

```
array<array<int, Size1>, Size2> multiDimensionalArrayInstace;
```

Even cooler, with C++11 and [Type aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), you can do

```
template <class InnerType, size_t Size1, size_t Size2>
using Matrix = array<array<InnerType, Size1>, Size2>;
```

which allows you to instantiate

```
Matrix<int,4,2> b;
```

as an equivalent to

```
array<array<int, 4>, 2> b;
```

Comment: It's `std::array` and C++ is case sensitive.