# Is it possible to return an a reference to the data in an std::vector, and preserve that reference after the vector goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, memory, stdvector

I am used to programming in C, and in that language I would just return a pointer to the data, and then the caller would be responsible for freeing the data, however, from what I've read, the vector's destructor will be called as soon as it goes out of scope, causing it's data to be de-allocated.

Once the reference is returned, the size of the contents will not change, so if I could just have a pointer to the data that I could manually delete afterwards that would be ideal. What I really *do not* want to do is copy all of the data into a new container, since this vector is going to grow to be very large.

Any help would be appreciated. Every solution I have seen so far involves either copying by value and relying on the compiler to optimize it, or using additional classes to wrap the vector.

Edit: To be clear, the only part of the vector which I want to keep is a pointer to its data (I.E. the pointer you get using the vector.data() method), I don't need to keep any other information about the original vector.

Comment: The whole point of a reference is that it doesn't own the object. It's perfectly valid to use a `std::unique_ptr` here.

Comment: No, although you could look into smart pointers. In c++ it would be copied, or simply returned as an object (possibly with a move constructor).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6211604/1766544

Comment: std::vector and most of containers in standard library support move semantics. if you have a function like std::vector<DataType> getData(...) { std::vector<DataType> result; // generate data; return result; } the result is moved and not copied. This is not a compiler optimization. So, someitmes returning a pointer is not neccessary.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I don't think that that is really the same as my problem, since in that case they are returning a vector, and in my case the function really needs to return a raw pointer.

Comment: A reference is not a raw pointer. If you need to USE a raw pointer with some other functions in an old C library, you can return std::vector and then get the pointer from that https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good (safe and fast) solution for the use case that you describe: Don't return a reference, return the vector to the outside of the scope instead.

> Is it possible to return an a reference to the data in an std::vector, and preserve that reference after the vector goes out of scope?

Yes... if you use static storage. The lifetime of objects with static storage duration extends until the end of the program. Therefore they stay alive when they go out of scope. Note that static storage is global state, which is often problematic. Avoid if you can and use with care.

With automatic storage: No.

---

> I would just return a pointer to the data, and then the caller would be responsible for freeing the data

This is a problematic approach. How does the caller know that they are responsible for freeing the data? How does the caller know how to free the data? How does the caller know when they can free the data (in case there are other users of the data)? This all relies on the caller to read the documentation, understand it, and not make a mistake. This is a source of many memory leaks, accesses through invalid pointers and double free crashes.

`std::vector` solves those problems (to some degree; there are no interfaces in C or C++ that cannot be misused if one tries hard enough) by keeping the lifetime tied to the container object.

---

> If I could just have a pointer to the data that I could manually delete afterwards that would be ideal.

You cannot have that. `std::vector` always destroys its data, and it is not possible to steal the data to the outside of the vector (except into another vector through move or swap).

Comment: The caller knows to free the data because the caller has already been written with the expectation that this function will produce a pointer. The data itself is just a bunch of primitives. Are you sure that there is no way to steal the data? I do not care if the original vector is unusable afterwards since its going to go out of scope immediately after.

Comment: @TrevorGalivan `The caller knows to free the data because the caller has already been written with the expectation that this function will produce a pointer.` Not all pointers are supposed to be freed by the caller. Example: strtok `Are you sure that there is no way to steal the data?` Yes.

Comment: Alright, thanks. So if I return the vector itself, will the data end up getting deep-copied? Or is it guaranteed to keep the data in place and only copy over other attributes of the vector?

Comment: @TrevorGalivan `will the data end up getting deep-copied? ` No. If anything is copied at all, it will be by move i.e. a shallow copy. Which in case of vector involves copying about 24 bytes, and a few others set to zero. But pretty much all compilers will elide the move so that nothing is copied at all.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of a reference is that it doesn't own the object. It's perfectly valid to use a `std::unique_ptr` here, which owns the object and can be returned to your caller.

Your function would be defined as follows (I assume a vector of integers), and C++14 or newer:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> getVector() {
    auto vec = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(/*any ctor args you want*/);
    // for example
    vec->push_back(1);
    vec->push_back(2);
    return vec;
}
```

A caller can then do as follows:

```
int main() {
    auto vec = getVector();
    std::cout << vec->size() << std::endl;
}
```

and the vector will be safely deleted as the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope. Note that if you are using C++11, you won't have `std::make_unique` and will need to do something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> vec(new std::vector<int>(/* ctor args */));
```

Comment: While it may technically do what OP asks for, I don't think there's a good reason to dynamically allocate a vector like this.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your code like this:

```
std::vector<blah> my_function_that_returns_a_vector ()
{
    std::vector <blah> v;
    ... code to populate v ...
    return v;
}
```

[NVRO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) will then eliminate the copy.  Instead, the vector returned is constructed directly in the caller's stack frame.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that NVRO is compiler- and settings-dependent, so cannot be guaranteed. However if you're using C++11 or later, *move semantics* will take over to accomplish more-or-less the same job: `std::vector` has a move constructor—you just need to ensure that the `blah` class does too.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to preserve the reference to a vector after it goes out of scope because, and you mentioned, it will be deleted. Once the vector is deleted, the memory stored at that address will be inaccessible. Alternatively, you can declare the variable outside of the scope, edit it within the scope. You mention returning by reference - is it possible that you can pass the vector into the function by reference, and simply return void? This way, you can edit the same vector in different scopes.